# Does Python's SQLAlchemy support server side cursor (for MSSQL)?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

I would like to query a MSSQL database using Python's SQLAlchemy.  There could be tens of millions of matched rows.  In order to use less memory at the server side, I consider using server-side cursor (SSCursor) to slice the matched rows.  However, I cannot find examples or resources about SSCursor with SQLAlchemy.

Is it possible to use SSCursor with SQLAlchemy?  If this is do-able, can someone show me examples or point out references?  If not, any suggested workarounds?

Thanks!

Comment: There currently isn't any MSSQL connector that supports server-side cursors.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You just specify the 'cursorclass' option in the connect_args argument. Here is an example with mysql. You'll need to use an MSSQL connector that implements server side cursors like `MySQLdb` does for mysql as shown below.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData
import MySQLdb.cursors
engine = create_engine('mysql://your:details@go/here', connect_args={'cursorclass': MySQLdb.cursors.SSCursor})
```

Comment: I didn't accept the answer because I didn't find SSCursor for MSSQL.  I googled for a while but got no luck :-(.  However, I up-voted your answer since you point out the connect_args argument.

Comment: There may be a connector that lazily fetches rows for MSSQL. oursql is supposed to do that for mysql.

Comment: SSCursor class isn't a cursor which supports server side cursors, it just reads the results in unbuffered mode.